# SIGSEGV Crash with NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have an app on the Mac App Store, and I get these crash reports from my users which I cannot reproduce or figure out how to debug. It seem like something crashes due to NSManagedObjectContext reset, but it's not obvious, and users don't have a reproducible case. The main thread can have a different stack trace, but the non-main thread always has the same stack trace.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x41bfc026bec0
Crashed Thread:  8

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: retain

Thread 0:
0   libFontParser.dylib                  0x00007fff8efa7921 _ZNK20TTrueTypeFontHandler11RenderGlyphEtR27TTrueTypeQuadOutlineContextj + 89
1   libFontParser.dylib                  0x00007fff8efa789e _ZNK20TTrueTypeFontHandler14GetOutlinePathEtRK18TGlyphOutlineBatch + 60
2   libFontParser.dylib                  0x00007fff8efa744a FPFontCopyGlyphPath + 394
3   CoreGraphics                         0x00007fff8767e913 CGFontCreateGlyphPath + 44
4   CoreGraphics                         0x00007fff8767e85d CGFontCreateGlyphBitmap + 437
5   CoreGraphics                         0x00007fff8767e607 _ZN14CGGlyphBuilder22create_missing_bitmapsEPK17CGGlyphIdentifiermPPK13CGGlyphBitmap + 109
6   libRIP.A.dylib                       0x00007fff8b7bec2d render_glyphs + 204
7   libRIP.A.dylib                       0x00007fff8b7bdf6f draw_glyph_bitmaps + 1585
8   libRIP.A.dylib                       0x00007fff8b7bd8cd ripc_DrawGlyphs + 2785
9   CoreGraphics                         0x00007fff87738077 draw_glyphs + 1034
10  CoreText                             0x00007fff8ac50426 _ZL25DrawSbixGlyphsAtPositionsPK5TFontP6CGFontRK6TCFRefIPK8__CFDataEPKtPK7CGPointmP9CGContext17CGAffineTransformSI_ + 2990
11  CoreText                             0x00007fff8abfdb73 CTFontDrawGlyphsWithAdvances + 789
12  UIFoundation                         0x00007fff966f212e -[NSLineFragmentRenderingContext drawAtPoint:inContext:] + 5398
13  UIFoundation                         0x00007fff96616728 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 16941
14  UIFoundation                         0x00007fff966108ff _NSStringDrawingCore + 150
15  AppKit                               0x00007fff93ce6d50 _NSDrawTextCell + 6954
16  AppKit                               0x00007fff9421cdf8 __47-[NSTextFieldCell drawLayer:inGraphicsContext:]_block_invoke + 576
17  AppKit                               0x00007fff944aa538 +[NSAppearance _performWithCurrentAppearance:usingBlock:] + 79
18  AppKit                               0x00007fff93cf6739 -[NSTextFieldCell drawLayer:inGraphicsContext:] + 225
19  AppKit                               0x00007fff93cf6470 +[NSGraphicsContext configureGraphicsContextForCALayer:withCGContext:andRenderWithHandler:] + 97
20  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939f1e93 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 3306
21  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939f11a3 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 59
22  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939f115f x_blame_allocations + 81
23  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939f0c5c _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1546
24  AppKit                               0x00007fff93ce039f _NSBackingLayerDisplay + 617
25  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939f0381 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 603
26  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939efabd _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 35
27  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939ef24e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
28  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939eeea4 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
29  QuartzCore                           0x00007fff939ffcad _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 71
30  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff8bbd0da7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
31  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff8bbd0d00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
32  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff8bbc2878 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328
33  HIToolbox                            0x00007fff918f1aef RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
34  HIToolbox                            0x00007fff918f176e ReceiveNextEventCommon + 179
35  HIToolbox                            0x00007fff918f16ab _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
36  AppKit                               0x00007fff93bb0f81 _DPSNextEvent + 964
37  AppKit                               0x00007fff93bb0730 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
38  AppKit                               0x00007fff93ba4593 -[NSApplication run] + 594
39  AppKit                               0x00007fff93b8fa14 NSApplicationMain + 1832
40  libdyld.dylib                        0x00007fff88d605c9 start + 1

...

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00007fff94d1b94a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fff9508740d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00007fff90c740dd objc_msgSend + 29
1   Foundation                           0x00007fff92461d24 NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread + 446
2   Foundation                           0x00007fff9240968f NSKeyValueWillChange + 465
3   Foundation                           0x00007fff924bc33e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _willChangeValuesForKeys:] + 234
4   CoreData                             0x00007fff8d9fdd6d -[NSFaultHandler turnObject:intoFaultWithContext:] + 221
5   CoreData                             0x00007fff8da28641 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _disposeObjects:count:notifyParent:] + 353
6   CoreData                             0x00007fff8da27c78 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _dispose:] + 392
7   CoreData                             0x00007fff8da27821 -[NSManagedObjectContext _dealloc__] + 337
8   CoreData                             0x00007fff8da563ab __internalBlockToDeallocNSManagedObjectContext_block_invoke + 75
9   CoreData                             0x00007fff8da1c246 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 182
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff8f122c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff8f126365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff8f127ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff8f1256b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff8f133fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fff95089637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00007fff9508740d start_wqthread + 13
```

Any idea how to find out what's causing the issue and possibly fix it? I've tried enabling zombies, setting NSBindingDebugLogLevel to 1, and running Zombies instrument, but no luck.

Comment: As described in [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944436/should-i-need-to-unbind-cocoa-bindings-in-dealloc-of-windowcontroller), I found that the MOC and the views to which it is bound tend to retain each other in ways that can burn you when you try to make the MOC reset, or dealloc the views.

Comment: I'm not doing a MOC reset, but the view gets deallocated by ARC. Should I try unbinding in the dealloc method? The frustrating part is that the problem isn't reproducible, at least when i try it. A few different users have reported the issue intermittently.

Comment: I found the explicit unbinding to be harmless.  You can definitely check to see if any view has extant bindings in dealloc, and log what they are.  Might show up even in a run where the binding doesn't fire

Comment: How would I check that the view has any active bindings?

Comment: I believe you have to query `infoForBinding:` for each of the `exposedBindings` on the view object.  Some sample code is in that problem I linked.

Comment: Looking again at the bottom of your stack trace, it looks like maybe a block you passed to performBlock retains a NSManagedObject... and I wonder if you have a property used for a binding where `atomic` would be appropriate?  Do you mostly use `nonatomic`?

Comment: I do use nonatomic mostly. I strongly suspect that this: `@property (strong, nonatomic) EKEventStore *syncEventStore;`  but no way to verify