# Getting error "libobjc.A.dylib`objc_assign_strongCast_non_gc(objc_object*, objc_object**)"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nszombieenabled

I have a huge set of data, those are displayed in a customized `NSOutlineView`.

Sometime my app gets crashed and gives me this error, while running in Xcode:

`libobjc.A.dylib`objc_assign_strongCast_non_gc(objc_object*, objc_object**)`

Any idea about this one? Your replies would certainly help me to figure it out.

*EDIT:*

What I have tried so far:

I have put all exception breakpoints and enabled `NSZombieEnabled`. But is never caught.

I have use Binding to populate the `NSOutlineView`.  The array contains one custom object, and the gets its values from aync server calls. If I do not open this `NSOutlineView` window, then every thing goes well.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? Stack trace? Error messages? Troubleshooting you've tried so far?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The whole stacktrace would be nice

Comment: It looks to me like an overreleased object. Have you tried running your code with NSZombieEnabled?

Comment: @JesseRusak: Yes the above screen shot is with ZombieEnabled only. What kind of issue is that, not able to understand. It i bypassing "All Exception Breakpoint" & "NSZombieEnable" both :(

Comment: Have you implemented `prepareForReuse` on any custom row or cell views?  I wonder if you're passing a nil-check into weird territory because a reused view retained an object that was bound to it.

Comment: Also, bindings, controllers, and views can create some strange retain cycles.  [I managed to EXEC_BAD_ACCESS because a managedObjectContext was retaining a controller which controlled a view that was deallocated.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944436/should-i-need-to-unbind-cocoa-bindings-in-dealloc-of-windowcontroller)