# binding not removed before view dealloc

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

In my NSDocument-based app, my document subclass creates and retains a "parameters" property during init and of course releases it during dealloc. This object is a collection of document properties and settings.

I have a DocumentWindowController that has a toolbar attached. One of the toolbar items is a segment control that controls the view style. This control's selected tag is bound in the nib to:

self.document.parameters.itemsViewStyle

The problem is that when I close my document, my DocumentWindowController gets deallocated, followed by my Document, which deallocates its DocumentParameters object.

```
An instance 0x6080000e4a80 of class DocumentParameters was deallocated while
key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x610000050dd0> (<NSKeyValueObservance
0x6080000cc6a0: Observer: 0x6080000cc630, Key path: itemsViewStyle, Options:
<New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x61800004a080>
```

It seems like the DocumentWindowController's toolbar should be breaking the binding to DocumentParameters, but it is not doing so.

What is going on here?

Comment: I experienced [exactly the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944436/should-i-need-to-unbind-cocoa-bindings-in-dealloc-of-windowcontroller).   There is a workaround there, but no good answer as to why binding magic does not always unbind everything that it should.

Comment: XIB or storyboard, Swift or Objective-C, ARC, type of `itemsViewStyle`?

Comment: itemsViewStyle is an NSNumber which is a property of my DocumentParameters object. DocumentParameters is not instantiated in a nib, but is created programmatically when the Document is created. This is Objective-C, non-ARC.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue but my document is deallocated before the windowcontroller and I don't get any complaints about observers.