# Storing and Retrieving Custom Object (ARC) Keeps growing memory

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nscoding, custom-object

hoping someone might be able to shed some light on the issue.

I am retrieving an array of custom objects using NSCoding + NSUserDefaults, and every time I reload the view, the memory continues to grow.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I use to retrieve the array of custom objects (which is called under ViewDidLoad:

```
NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray;

NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
dataRepresentingSavedArray = nil;
dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"women"];
if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
{
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = nil;
    oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        women = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    else
        women = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

The woman.backgroundimage is what causes the most memory loss, however when I removed that aspect from the custom object and NSCoder completely it still climbed in memory without release, but slower. The ViewController is part of a navigation controller (SWRevealViewController Pod) and when it is selected the memory increases until app crash. Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I figured I should also share how the data is archived. First the image is compressed:

```
                 CGFloat maxCompressionFactor = 0.1f;
                 CGFloat compressionFactor = 0.9f;
                 int maxImageSize = 60 * 1024;

                 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_theimage, compressionFactor);

                 while ([imageData length] > maxImageSize && compressionFactor > maxCompressionFactor)
                 {
                     compressionFactor = 0;
                     imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_theimage, compressionFactor);
                 }

                 _theimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                 _theimage = [self scaleImage:_theimage toSize:CGSizeMake(320.0,480.0)];
```

Then all values are stored:

```
 //store to woman object
                 Woman* woman = [[Woman alloc] initWithFull:nameOfGirl withdate2:date withintervalLength:string  withperiodLength:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"432000"] withpmsLength:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"432000"]initWithbackground:_theimage];

                 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

                 [women addObject:woman];

                 [userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Where is the women mutable array declared?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I declare it in the .h as  `@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *women;`

Comment: I don't like that you replace a VC property (`women`) with a completely new array.  You're changing the memory location that `women` points to.  Why not use `[women setArray:oldSavedArray]`?  Then, if something in the view or view controller is retaining `women`, you'd at least not have the previous `women` object around.  Unfortunately, that wouldn't solve anything that might be retaining an object within the array.  I would try hard to avoid replacing the data model object that backs a view object without deleting the old view object too. I think the view or controller is retaining something

Comment: that actually reduced the growth down to about .5-1 MB per load. Thank you. When the app returns active and I reload, I still loose about 20Mb. It doesn't release still. By your last thought did you mean I should make sure that (for example) the string object "woman.girlname" should not be assigned to an NSString which is recreated on every load? and should the NSString it be a VC property?

Comment: The real problem here is that there's a view or controller object that's retaining something old that you want to replace with fresh data.   But your `alloc`s are exacerbating that issue, because each `alloc` creates another object that can become a zombie.  On the other hand, if you basically use the API equivalent of assignment to the dereferenced property, you still have something retaining that object, but at least you haven't created a new one.

Comment: I'd start trying to nil everything out when the view becomes inactive, and wrap the nilling in an `autoreleasepool` enclosure.  I did this sort of work on OSX 3 years ago, but you can [at least get this gist of it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944436/should-i-need-to-unbind-cocoa-bindings-in-dealloc-of-windowcontroller).

Comment: setting the storyboard outlet backgroundimage.image to nil and wrapping in autorelease like you suggested has solved the memory issue. Thank you! I would like to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just a synopsis of the comments.

The key to understanding what was going on was that some object-- likely the view controller itself, but potentially a custom view object, whatever-- was retaining the objects that you were creating from `NSUserDefaults`.

We reduced the number of `alloc`s, and the amount of memory growth reduced, which seemed to confirm that each time `ViewDidLoad` is hit, an object was created but never deallocated because its retain count never hit zero.  Some other object which stayed in memory was keeping a strong reference to it.

At that point, I simply suggested aggressive `nil` assignment in the right view lifecycle function (`viewDidDisappear`?), wrapped in an `@autoreleasepool` enclosure for good measure.  That turns out to solve the problem entirely.

Assigning `nil` to the property within the VC ensures that a `strong` property's data does not stay in memory until the VC itself is deallocated.  Using `@autoreleasepool` tells ARC to deallocate zero-reference-count objects that became zero-reference-count within the enclosure at the termination of the enclosure.  I'm thinking of the "pool" as a ledger of reference count transactions within the enclosure.  The enclosure keeps its own ARC books and clears its ledger when it's done.